# Changing state of third party React component from parent

Tags: reactjs

I'm using a third party component for date picking, and I want to update its date state from its parent component. Since it's a third party component I'm a bit restricted - like for example telling it to listen for a state change.

Any thoughts? I'd like to do something like:

`childComponent.state.dateRange = newState;` 
or 
`childComponent.setState({foo: newState});`

Comment: You can't change state of any other component.I'm sure they would give a way to pass the data as props;

Comment: This would be impossible unless you modify the 3rd party component somewhat. For example, you could add you could pass in a prop that is managed in the subcomponent and updates its state.

Comment: Can you add details about the third party component you're using?

Comment: @PraneshRavi I'm using react-date-picker's MultiMonthView component. Example here: http://zippyui.com/docs/react-date-picker/examples/1

Answer (score 0):

You can use the state of the parent to change the date of the datepicker. See the following example

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      date: '20/04/2016 16:23:56',
    }
  }
  changeDate(newDate) {
    this.setState({
       date: newDate, //Change the date here
    })
  }
  render() {
   return <Calendar
      dateFormat="DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss"
      defaultDate={this.state.date}
    />
  }
}
```

Call the `changeDate()` using `this.ChangeDate` with the `newDate` as the parameter. This will change the date of the datepicker.

Hope it helps.